# Ripple: How is an UNL (unique node list) constructed?

Tags: ripple

I am interested in UNL construction.
If some server S is on the UNL of server T, does this imply that server T is on the UNL of server S?
Or in other words if I constructed an UNL graph would it be a directed graph?

Comment: If you haven't looked at https://wiki.ripple.com/Unique_Node_List it might be able to help explain some.

Comment: @CharlesS It's worth noting that the wiki page is more than a year old, and might be substantially out of date.

Comment: No doubt. That's why I posted as a comment. Just giving a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Most servers aren't validators and so cannot appear on anyone else's UNL.

Comment: What if both nodes T, S are validators? If T adds S to its UNL, does S add T to its own UNL?

Comment: That's up to S.